# how to switch to 'git' user on aws EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, gitlab

I've installed gitlab on EC2 and now I have to change server URL.

The .deb package installs everything as "git" user and now I can't see config files 'cause via SSH i'm logged as "ubuntu".

I switched user with `sudo su - ubuntu` but when I try to nano a file, it asks for "git user password".

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `sudo bash` followed by `su - git`?

If that fails, you can try changing the git user password using `passwd git` from the root shell. If that causes problems, you can always re-install from the image.

Comment: I was able to change password for the user "git" and open .conf file. But when I try to save, it says Permission Denied. Any idea? Thanks for helping!

Comment: They've really locked things down. Two things to check. Look at the file permissions and ownership using `ls -l filename`. Also you can try editing the file as root.